# What's the difference between onError in subscribe and catch operator?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I've came across two types of error handling in RxJS:

- using the second argument (`onError`) in the `subscribe`
- using the `catch` operator.

What is the difference between them? What are some textbook examples or rule-of-a-thumbs for using either of them?

---

```
this.stream$.subscribe(callback, err => console.error(err))

// vs

this.stream$.catch(err => console.error(err)).subscribe(callback)
```

Comment: cf https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93, the part on error propagation

Comment: The selector function passed to the [`catch`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-catch) operator returns an observable that's used to continue the chain. There is no analogous behaviour for the error handler passed to `subscribe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you would get the same output in both cases.  As for rules of thumb:

- Use `do` if you want to **do something with the error** (e.g. log it) and you **do not want to create a subscription**.  You might do this if you were, for example, wrapping some library (e.g. angular's `Http` library) in a generic wrapper that adds logging (maybe pops up a toast at the bottom of the screen when an error occurs).
- Use `subscribe` if you want to **do something with the error** (e.g. log it) and you want to **create a subscription**.  Keeping with that `Http` example this might be if you want to kick off a request and display any error that surfaces in the same place you were going to put the response.
- Use `catch` if you want to **handle the error and recover**.  For example, maybe you want to catch a 401 error, refresh login credentials, and then retry the request.

In your example, since you are just logging the error, `catch` would be inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The callback on a `subscribe` is the end of the chain, you just listen to the result.

`catch` is an operator that lets you change the behavior of your observable when an error is thrown or just replace the error with another value. `catch` expect you to do something, to return a new observable not just listen to it.

Also, you can use `do` inside a chain to listen to an observable like you do on subscribe.

***For RxJs 6 ***

Use `tap` instead of `do`.
Use `catchError` instead of `catch`.
Use `finalize` instead of `finally`

And for all of the parameters above, you need to use a pipe:

```
this.service.getItem()
    .pipe(
        map((data) => this.onSuccess(data)),
        catchError(error => of(this.handleError(error))),
        finalize(() => this.stopLoading())
    )
    .subscribe();
```

Also, imports have changed. Now you should import like that:

```
Import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Plus, you don't need to import pipe.